# Find excel worksheet with vb script

Tags: windows-vista, microsoft-excel-2007, find, vbscript

Is there a way in windows vista to search for an excel 2007 workbook that contains a certain vbscript (or filter those files that contain any Vb script ?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, Excel 2007 workbooks with any VBA code must be saved as macro-enabled workbooks with file extension .xlsm.  I would just search for that file type.